# Checking if string contains other strings

Tags: c#, strings, extension-methods

This is simply an extension method which checks if a string `str` contains all the values in `values`.

However, there are cases when `str` might be null, `values` might be null, or any item in `values` might be null. I am handling those cases by using the ternary `?:`, null-conditional `?.` and null-coalesce `??` operators.

Should this piece of code be refactored?

```
public static bool ContainsAll(this string str, string[] values)
{
    return str == null ? false : values?.All(v => str.Contains(v ?? "")) ?? false;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it self-explanatory?

Comment: I cannot pass null to `string.Contains()`, hence `v ?? ""` returns v, if non-null, otherwise "".

Comment: Now it looks much better and I give you +1 for the improvements ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like the ternary operator but in this case I wouldn't use it because a single expression that makes sure both variables are valid and then searching for the strings is easier to understand I think.

The `v ?? ""` isn't very pretty, especially the `""` part which actually should be `string.Empty`. You could get rid of it by filtering the array and skipping the empty and null elements.

```
public static bool ContainsAll(this string str, params string[] values)
{
    return 
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && 
        values != null &&
        values
            .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
            .All(v => str.Contains(v));
}
```

If you decorate the second parameter with [`params`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword then you can just type the values without an array (if you need to):

```
"text".ContainsAll("t", null);
```

Comment: [Personally I wouldn't go with string.Empty. But I'll leave it to whatever the preferences are for any one team](http://stackoverflow.com/a/263257/1277156).